# Failed to map SQL query to topology on data node

Tags: java, kubernetes, ignite

I have 3 Ignite servers running in Kubernetes. I set up them last night. and the following query was working fine.

```sql
select distinct u.userId,u.attempts,u.passwordCreatedOn,u.password from  users u inner join users_roles ur on ur.userId = u.userId inner join roles r on r.roleId = ur.roleId 
         where lower(u.email) = 'some@email.com'   and r.organizationId = 23 and r.isActive = 1 and ur.isActive = 1 and u.isActive = 1;
```

But the next morning I was getting the following error upon running the above query :

```sh
SQL Error [50000]: Failed to map SQL query to topology on data node [dataNodeId=6c26a6d5-1ba1-432f-9e72-05a23da76275, msg=Failed to execute non-collocated query (will retry) [localNodeId=6c26a6d5-1ba1-432f-9e72-05a23da76275, rmtNodeId=6c26a6d5-1ba1-432f-9e72-05a23da76275, reqId=34201, errMsg=Timeout reached.]]
```

I am using Ignite 2.8.1 version

Please suggest.

Comment: how did you set them up? what guide did you follow

Comment: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/stateful-deployment

Comment: most probably you have some issue on the server-side, please provide full logs from all nodes and the time when you have this error.